# Can I get past information of what I typed in my computer or laptop with my keyboard

Tags: password-management

Once I forget my ID's password. I recovered it and changed it about a month ago but I forget again.

Is there any way to see the details stored in laptop what i typed in past to till now from my keyboard of laptop without using a keylogger?

Comment: **No**. The keyboard buffer is small, quickly overwritten and stored in volatile memory.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you had a keylogger running, there's no way to get all the data you typed on your keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can't recover it that way, but you could try dumping the password hashes (assuming you're talking about a local account). If you can't break the hash, you can simply replace it with a hashed version of another string. Maybe try using HBCD? Unless your disk is encrypted.